# Term for closing a stock trade?

Tags: single-word-requests, finance

I'm TA:ing a programming course and am writing up the instructions for a lab in which the students will implement a toy stock trading platform. I'm not too familiar with financial lingo, so there is this one term I need some help with.

What's the term generally used for a completed trade? That is, I want to buy 10 shares in X at $10 per share, you want to sell 10 shares in X at $10 per share, so I buy your 10 shares and now we have a... what?

Comment: Why aren't you happy with the term you used yourself in the question? *"...I buy your 10 shares and now we have a **completed trade**"*.

Comment: Is there no specific term used for this in English then? Literally translated from my native language, such a completed trade would be called a *close* and is more specific than just a "completed trade".

Comment: The trade is closed,  or settled after delivery of shares vs payment.

Comment: Well, you're obviously familiar with the ***close*** usage in English, since your question title refers to ***closing** a stock trade*. All of which suggests you *already* know "normal" English usage in this general area. I think you might be well advised to avoid too much domain-specific terminology (which is probably Off Topic anyway). For example, despite the fact that I'm a perfectly competent native speaker, I had to Google **abbreviation ta** to figure out what on earth the second "word" in your question meant. Specialist terminology is for geeks, not normal people.

Comment: A "closed trade" or a "confirmed trade." And @FumbleFingers a TA is not a technical term in the USA.

Comment: @CarSmack: I never said TA was a "technical term" - I was simply making the point that even if there *was* a domain-specific term for what OP seeks, he might do well to note that it's not always a good idea to use terms that only people specialising in that domain would understand. OP is obviously so steeped in the teaching profession that not only does he not mind using a somewhat opaque abbreviation - he goes even further by converting the noun to a verb, and introducing totally non-standard orthography (the "internal colon"). Clarity counts for a lot more than "knowing the right word".

Comment: @FumbleFingers TA, as a verb or noun, is not an opaque (even somewhat) abbreviation to *college-educated Americans.* Pardon **valderman** for using an Americanism in his or her quest to find out if a specific English word exists. I was under the impression that specificity engenders clarity.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the audacity to not be college-educated American, and even though we have the term TA to mean "Teaching Assistant" here in the UK, and even though I have several teachers in the family using that term, I did not realise that was what was meant here. I'm with FumbleFingers on this one, especially as that narrative is completely superfluous to the actual question. Leave domain specific initialisms out please people, it makes it easier for everyone to understand the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so we're clear on this:

1. My *expressed desire to buy* 10 shares of AAPL is called a ***bid***
2. Your *expressed desire to sell* 10 shares of AAPL is called an ***offer*** (or ***ask***)

The hypernym for *bid* and *offer* is ***quote***, and the instruction by which you express this *quote* is an ***order***; but, critically, *n̲o̲n̲e̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲s̲e̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲n̲g̲s̲ ̲i̲s̲ ̲a̲ ̲t̲r̲a̲d̲e̲*.

So what do you call it when my *bid* (*order to buy*) matches your *offer* (*order to sell*) such that I get your stock, and you get my cash?

That is the ***trade***. *The word you're looking for is **trade***. The trade is distinguished from the earlier actions (*bidding*, *offering*) because those are quotes: desires, intents; the *trade* is the *transaction*.

Therefore, there is no need for additional adjectives, or a different word, for a "done" trade or a "closed" trade; a trade is, *by definition*, closed and done.

---

<sup>Aside: you will sometimes hear "*closed trade*" in the securities industry, but here "*trade*" is used metaphorically or figuratively to mean "*trading idea*", or "*strategy*", and is technically a closed "*position*", which takes two actual, literal, *trades* to effect (one to *open the position*, and the other to *close the position*, and capture the profit or loss).</sup>

<sup>Also, in the specific scenario you're describing, where one student in your class is trading with another student in your class, and neither one has to go to the open market to find a counterparty, what you've got is an ***internal cross*** or just ***cross*** (which is done -- you guessed it -- through *internalization*).</sup>

<sup>In the US, all trades, whether internalized (*crossed*) or done on a public exchange or ATS (where orders are said to be *matched* as opposed to *crossed*), are still required to be reported to the public, and so your students' internal trade will still show up on the *tape* as a *tick*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> I want to buy 10 shares in X at $10 per share, you want to sell 10 shares in X at $10 per share, so I buy your 10 shares and now we have a...

...deal.

You have agreed terms, you have executed the trade, you have a (done) deal.

I cannot think of a general single-word term to describe making the agreements and doing the trade. However as a point of interest (hopefully), in the insurance sector (UK) the term 'bind' refers to the moment the prospective Insured accepts the terms, promises to pay the money and therefore instates the insurance. From the moment the "risk" is "bound" the insured is covered. I don't think this word-use applies to any other transaction though.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/01/022801.asp), *Understanding Order Execution*, an order is completed when it is **filled**.

> Often investors and traders alike do not fully understand what happens when you click the "enter" button on your online trading account. If you think your order is always **filled** immediately after you click the button in your account, you are mistaken. In fact, you might be surprised at the variety of possible ways in which an order can be **filled** and the associated time delays.

In the [Investopedia dictionary](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fill.asp):

> Fill: The action of completing or satisfying an order for a security or commodity. It is the basic act in transacting stocks, bonds or any other type of security.

Comment: Yes, but here each student has an order, and each order gets filled, and so you're dealing with **two** fills, as opposed to the singular transaction (the *trade*) the OP is trying to name.  See my answer.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. A trade requires a buy order and a sell order. A buy order without a corresponding sell order cannot be considered filled.

Comment: And, I guess while I'm being pedantic about this: a *fill* can be *partial*; such that if the two students' *prices* agree, but *quantities* differ, one student can get a *partial fill* (say, 5 shares instead of 10), so at least that student *would not* consider the trade "complete" (he'd have to wait, or go elsewhere, to get his remaining 5 shares).

Comment: It might help, while being pedantic, to provide one or more citations to (purportedly) authoritative references.

Comment: Yes? What did I say that contradicted your statement? What I said is there will be *two fills*. Not one fill. Each student gets a fill (the *buy order* gets filled, and the *sell order* gets filled, and, as I said above, it's possible that one of the orders doesn't even get *completely* filled). And there two fills do not correspond to the *singular, atomic transaction* OP is seeking. Dig?

Comment: I could if you like, but you already know at least one place to look, you linked to it in your answer.